# Which is Easier to create an .exe file ,Vb or python with tkinter?

Tags: python, vb.net, tkinter

I'm making an small audio editor interface, it needs to have a dialog box with 3-4 button options along with activate option, when the user clicks on activate,another dialog box will be popped asking him for his Mac address and a code, i heard Visual basic is good for making .exe but does it give me full control over the application?

Answer (score 2):

You have to think about where your strengths lie.  If you are a strong Python coder then go in that direction.  if you are a strong VB coder then go in that direction.   I would argue that neither of the options you are thinking of using would be ideal.

I would actually recommend C# within Visual Studio 2015 community.   Python isn't natively compiled to an EXE and there are more hoops to jump though to get a compiled executable.

Recently I used C# and Visual Studio 2015 community to create myself a similar small GUI interface for the work I was doing.    I have previously used Python with QT.  The extra hoops I had to work through to get an EXE from python definatly made the choice of python at the time a downside.

C# has a large amount of libraries available for it using the NUGET libraries in Visual Studio.   VB is quite dated (but still quite usable) compare to C#.

Python also has a large number of currently supported opensource libaries.

Comment: but i don't have any experience in c# nor Visual std.2015,so if i start from scratch will it be efficient?

Answer (score 2):

As you don't have any experience on C# (As mentioned in a comment) then you should go with VB.Net. I guess it has all the features you described you needed. But I would recommend you to learn C# as soon as possible if you want to become a good Coder because C# language is similar to many other famous/ popular and strong Coding Languages so it will be easier to learn other languages too when you would need them.

> I too don't have much knowledge about C# and am trying to learn it. Believe me it's much more convenient than VB.Net as per my few experience.